# How do I stop nividia xorg.conf file from reverting after reboot

Tags: nvidia, xorg.conf

I am trying to add coolbits option to the nividia x server settings. When altering the xorg.conf file in nano everything takes.

When I reboot to access the new options in the x server settings, the xorg.conf file has erased all changes made to it.

Please help. I am very new to linux. started 2 days ago

Comment: You want to create a .conf file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ ` that has your coolbits section. Maybe post what you were  adding to xorg.conf that worked & someone can craft an exact answer for you.